# Create a JSON or slice array in Go

Tags: json, go

I am not sure how to do this or word this. I have a variable that returns a string something like this:

```
unixCommands := exec.Command("ls", "/bin")
unixCommandsout, err := unixCommands.Output()
unixCommandsstring := string(unixCommandsout)
fmt.Printf(unixCommandsstring)
```

Output:

```
unicode_start
unicode_stop
unlink
usleep
vi
view
ypdomainname
zcat
```

I'm looking for creating a JSON array or whatever is easiest to get to this final output:

```
["unicode_start", "unicode_stop", "unlink", "usleep", "vi", "view", "ypdomainname", "zcat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with package `encoding/json`:

```
outputSlice := strings.Split(unixCommandsstring,"\n")
js,_ := json.Marshal(outputSlice)
fmt.Print(string(js))
```

Comment: of course in a production system you would actually capture the error from `json.Marshal` and do something with it :)

Comment: @ScallioXTX No, that's not needed here. `json.Marshal` never fails when passed a string slice.

Comment: @rightfold, so you know *exactly* what the current and *all future* implementations of JSON marshalling will do for all possible inputs (e.g. unicode, invalid UTF-8, out of memory/buffer, etc, etc)?? It's far easier and better habit to check the `error` return whenever it is provided. If you *think* it will never fail then maybe use panic (but in this case of course the `os.Exec` can fail so the surrounding function will need to return errors anyway). Suggesting that errors can be ignored is foolhardy.

Comment: lol, this is a great comment thread "checking errors vs not" =P